# изменить в htaccess mysite.com/aaa на mysite.com/bbb/aaa

Tags: .htaccess

нужно в .htaccess произвести замену **БЕЗ ПЕРЕЗАПИСИ В АДРЕСНОЙ СТРОКЕ**
с mysite.com/aaa  на  mysite.com/bbb/aaa

То есть чтобы в адресной сроке высвечивалось mysite.com/aaa,
а на страничке отображалось mysite.com/bbb/aaa

Возможно?

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал вот так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^aaa$ bbb/aaa [L,QSA]
```